# Change ttyUSB permissions using udev

Tags: ubuntu, tty, udev

My program needs to access `ttyUSB` without root permission.

I tried changing it with `chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` as you know, when I reboot this permission changed to default. How can I configure my udev rules.d for this?

Comment: You're asking for the incorrect solution to the access problem.  Proper solution for access to a serial terminal device is to add your username to the `dialout` group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for `ttyUSB*` in the `rules.d` directory and update it to look lke below:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", MODE="0777"
```

Leave any other entries you find on the line unchanged, add the mode attribute if it does not exist.

Comment: A valid answer to a misguided question makes it an improper solution to the real problem.

Comment: @sawdust why misguided?

Comment: @YanFoto --  It's an example of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  See my other comment above to the question itself.