# cannot open /dev/ttyusb0 using python and pyserial

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyserial

I am writing a python script whose purpose is to communicate with serial devices. 
In order to do that, I am using pySerial to open the device's serial port but when i tried running the script on linux platform I couldn't open the device's serial port and got an error "Access denied". 
I am looking for a permanent solution (I don't want to print in cmd:

```
 sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

each time I want to access the port). Any recommendations please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change ttyUSB permissions using udev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291431/change-ttyusb-permissions-using-udev)

Comment: It tried what you have recommended and the error changed to Input/output error instead of permission denied but  i still couldn't open the port

Comment: Do not change the privileges of the device node.  Do not use superuser mode, i.e. `sudo`.   The proper solution is to add your username to the `dialout` group, which is the group that owns serial terminal device nodes.  And this question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the python script with sudo? And what is the specific error?